# Why would my fragment crash when reloading the loader?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-loadermanager

While I have been unable to duplicate this bug, I still get a trickle of crash reports with this occurring.  I thought adding a null check for my list adapter would fix it, but its still occurring.  What am I missing?

Full stacktrace:
http://pastebin.com/Q6GwDU7Q

```
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    final int id = loader.getId();
    switch (id) {
    case LOADER_ID1:
        if (mAdapter != null)
            mAdapter.changeCursor(null); //Line 512 where stacktrace references
        break;
    case LOADER_ID2:
        //Other code here
        break;
    default:
        throw new InvalidParameterException("id=" + id);
    }
}
```

mAdapter is initialized in onActivityCreated, but I realize while typing this I do not ever release it, maybe I should perform that in onDetach?  mAdapter is attached to a ListView set up by a ListFragment.  And I set the adapters cursor to null to clear the list I have.  So yes, what am I overlooking?

Comment: I can't imagine that it's the source of your NPE, but I believe that you should be using `swapCursor`  instead of `changeCursor` because the loader 'owns' the cursor and will close it. `swapCursor` doesn't close the old cursor, while `changeCursor` does.

Comment: I get what you're saying now, I will see if I can duplicate this so I can try your solution.

Comment: Granted, issue 54142 (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=54142) suggests what I thought would happen

Comment: Well, that's a really nasty bug that I (and I assume most people) didn't know about :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after searching through the Android source, I see now that like GreyBearedGeek stated, I should allow the loader to handle the Cursor destruction.

As you can see in CursorLoader it will handle closing the old cursor if passing a new one:

```
    /* Runs on the UI thread */
@Override
public void deliverResult(Cursor cursor) {
    if (isReset()) {
        // An async query came in while the loader is stopped
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
        return;
    }
    Cursor oldCursor = mCursor;
    mCursor = cursor;

    if (isStarted()) {
        super.deliverResult(cursor);
    }

    if (oldCursor != null && oldCursor != cursor && !oldCursor.isClosed()) {
        oldCursor.close();
    }
}
```

As well as closing the cursor upon a reset.

```
    @Override
protected void onReset() {
    super.onReset();

    // Ensure the loader is stopped
    onStopLoading();

    if (mCursor != null && !mCursor.isClosed()) {
        mCursor.close();
    }
    mCursor = null;
}
```

So I will use swapCursor in the future as to not interfere with CursorLoaders handling, even though I've yet to see how this causes my NPE in the stacktrace above.